# Визуализация графа с помощью Graphviz

Tags: c#, графы, graphviz

Как отобразить на форме граф с помощью данной библиотеки?

Comment: Graphviz рисует рисунки, на форме вам только рисунок и остается вывести. А таких примеров на оффсайте хватает.

Comment: @Monk мне не удалось найти конкретного примера, как с нуля или с dot-языка нарисовать граф. не могли бы вы поделиться парой примеров?

Comment: Так, про оффсайт видимо наврал, сам смотрел тут - http://graphs.grevian.org/example

Comment: И ещё можно пользоваться кодом для генерации графа, а потом кормить графвизу. Либа называется quickgraph, подключается графвиз просто https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visualization%20Using%20Graphviz&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @Monk спасибо, разобрался